# How to user userdefaults to open a tableview with last cell pressed on top position

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying that when I use close an app and start it again a tableview put the last cell pressed on the top. I'm able to store the last cell position with the next code and even move to the top position when press the cell. But I don't now how force the table move to that position when the user comes back.The table has only one section. I'm reading several posts but I don't know how to adapt the solution to my code. Please help!
My code is:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath.row, forKey: "celdaPulsada")
    let celdaPulsada =  UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "celdaPulsada")
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.moveRow(at:[0,celdaPulsada], to: [0, 0])
    tableView.endUpdates()
 }
```

Comment: self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .none, animated: true)

Comment: but where do I have to add that code?

Comment: when user comeback to specific vc in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Comment: I've tried both load and appear but nothing happens    let celdaPulsada =  UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "celdaPulsada")
        print(celdaPulsada)
     
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: [0,celdaPulsada], at: .none, animated: true)

Comment: I've added full source code in answer with dummy data please check and update it according to your requirements

Comment: replace .none to .top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the demo code please modify it according to your requirement

```
  import UIKit
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController  {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            setupView()
            scrollTableViewToLastSelectedPosition()
        }
        
        private func setupView() {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
        }
        
        private func scrollTableViewToLastSelectedPosition() {
            let celdaPulsada =  UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "celdaPulsada")
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: celdaPulsada, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
        }
    }
    
    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell No \(indexPath.row + 1)"
            return cell
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath.row, forKey: "celdaPulsada")
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 50
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: It worked but the problem it's that your code scroll the table but I wanted to move the cell to the top.

Comment: @Naqueeb sorry to bothering you again but it have double checked now and I've realised that it only works when it viewWillAppear but not when viewDidLoad....so the first time it's not working after I press I cell and came back it works , any suggestion? Thanks Im using your full codex.

Comment: Once you tap the cell value will be saved in userDefaults so first time it will be in default position. 
2nd ViewDidload only call once when view Loaded to memory so please check view life cycle and place your code according to need

Comment: But the problem is that when I tap the cell value and It's saved If I closed the app and start again it should scroll the cell to top position but it doesnt do. I can read the userDefaults saved but It doesnt nove neither viewDidLoad nor viewWillAppear. suggestion?